# "Compose" a class and a function

Tags: android, kotlin

In an app of mine, I have a database, and a class with a lot of functions. After each call of any function in the class, I would like to run a function to update the database. How do I do that cleverly, that is, without appending a function at the end of each function of my class ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Although I never used it with Kotlin, have you checke Guice? Here is an article going over Guice + Kotlin => https://medium.com/faun/implementing-aspect-oriented-programming-in-kotlin-with-guice-2b6350c83e6e